# 'Failed to build gem native extension' when running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, windows-10, bundler

When I run "bundle install" in my project directory I get the following error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20161028-11856-1tljde.rb extconf.rb
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
checking for clockid_t in time.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... no
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for poll() in poll.h... no
checking for getaddrinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... no
getaddrinfo required
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/Ruby22/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-rtlib
        --without-rtlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/kgio-2.9.2
for inspection.
Results logged to
c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/kgio-2.9.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing kgio (2.9.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install kgio -v '2.9.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#don't upgrade
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'rack', '1.4.0'

ruby '2.2.5'


gem 'rack-attack'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'foreman'

group :development do
  gem 'brakeman'
  gem 'bundler-audit'
  gem 'guard-brakeman'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-shell'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rack-livereload'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'travis-lint'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

gem 'gauntlt'

gem 'simplecov', :require => false, :group => :test

group :development, :test do
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.14.2'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
 gem 'bcrypt'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
 gem 'unicorn'

# Pow related gem
gem 'powder'

gem 'aruba'
#gem 'minitest', '~> 4.0', :require=> "minitest/autorun"

#gem 'minitest'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'

# Add SMTP server support using MailCatcher
gem 'mailcatcher'
```

I am running on windows 10 with ruby 2.2.5
I'm not sure what the rails version is due to the fact that I am getting an error when I try ' rails -v'. I don't think that's the reason I am facing that error above because the 'rails -v' error is something recent.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `gem 'unicorn'` in your Gemfile?

Unicorn required `kgio` that failed to install and I'm not sure that this gem works on Window. Try to change server from `unicorn` to `thin` - it's ok for development.

Also you can specify the platform for gems in your Gemfile

```
platforms :ruby do #unux
  gem 'unicorn'
end

platforms :mswin do
  #gems specific to windows
end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you for your response. I will try to change from unicorn to thin. However would it be possible to explain to me a bit more (in layman terms maybe?) the second part of your answer? I am still a very new to coding and I am already having trouble **just setting up** in order to start.

Comment: In Gemfile you can specify gems that will be installed for different platforms. In case that I show in my answer **gem unicorn** will be installed when you run your application on UNIX systems like ubuntu or MacOS. Gems that in `:mswin` block will be installed when you run bundle and your application on Windows platform. You can read a bit about groups here: [bundler groups doc](http://bundler.io/groups.html) and [bundler gemfile groups](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#GROUPS)

Comment: Alright I see. Another noob question: why can't I find the the :mswin block in my gemfile? Or do you mean I should add it myself?

Comment: you should add it